# How convert these output into human readable format

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark

I just ping the google.com, then i checked in the wireshark it give some output icmp. Like this

```
0000  c8 d3 a3 c9 a6 f4 9c 2a  70 cd f2 c5 08 00 45 00   .......* p.....E.
0010  00 54 6c b0 40 00 40 01  d5 89 c0 a8 01 02 4a 7d   .Tl.@.@. ......J}
0020  ec 47 08 00 f7 14 4b 6b  00 02 ae d2 d4 54 00 00   .G....Kk .....T..
0030  00 00 65 83 0e 00 00 00  00 00 10 11 12 13 14 15   ..e..... ........
```

Following outputs are need to convert into human readable format

```
.......* p.....E.
.Tl.@.@. ......J}
.G....Kk .....T..
..e..... ........
```

How to convert into human readable formart

Comment: The second section which you highlighted is in a Human readable form, ie. `2a 70` is `*p` - it is unclear what you want ?

Comment: Try piping to `text2pcap - - | tshark -Vi -`

Comment: what do you mean by human readable ? humans do read alfanumeric characters .

Comment: do you mean you wan to see ip address , tcp flags , port numbers or alike things ?

Comment: @soubunmei  yes i want

Comment: text2pcap - - | tshark -Vi -                                           
Input from: Standard input

Output to: Standard output

Capturing on Standard input


How to get the output?

Comment: do you copy the lines from a window , or have you already saved the data on disk and just xxd'ing for us ? anyway you may want to edit your post .

Comment: Why don't you just use `tcpdump`? It displays the packets in human-readable format.

Comment: @Barmar   yes I know tcpdump it will display human readable format. Why can't we convert the output of wireshark ?

Comment: You can save from Wireshark to a file, and then use `tcpdump -r filename` to display the file.

Answer (score 2):

One of Wireshark's main *purposes* is to produce human-readable format; if you've captured traffic in Wireshark, you can either just view it, or, when exporting the dissection as text, export the dissections, not just the hex dump.

I.e., it *already* gave you "ip address , tcp flags , port numbers [and] alike things".  It took the raw binary form of the hex data and dissected it.  You can even save that to a text file, just as you can save the hex data to a text file.

If you want a *program* to do that, Stéphane's suggestion will, in effect, get the Wireshark dissection code to re-do what it had already done.

If you want to do it yourself - i.e., you want to understand what the bytes mean - try looking at the packets within Wireshark, and then look at documents such as [the Wikipedia article on Ethernet frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) (trying to read the IEEE 802.3 standard would be like trying to get a sip of water from a fire hose) and either:

- the official documents such as [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) for IPv4, [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) for ICMP, and [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) for TCP (although those are a bit like the aforementioned fire hose)

or

- less formal documents such as the Wikipedia articles for [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), and [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (not to be confused with [the other TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_(antiseptic))), and other pages to which they point.